# Is there a package installer in which a i can choose where to install?

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, directory, paths

Since changing the installation path or directory of dpkg is not a good and risky idea I would like to know if there are any package installers in which I can choose to install where I want since my disk is running out of space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If you want full control over software installation you either use dpkg or a source install.

I myself would fix "since my disk is running out of space?" instead of going through hoops as this is a problem in itself.  How large is your `/`? It myself tend to use 25Gb but hardly get over 10Gb when it is time to install a new release.

If you have more then 10, 15Gb software installed you should consider removing unneeded software. If you have personal data in their it is best to move that to another partition.

Add space to root, get a larger disk, or mount parts of your base install (that would be `/var/` and `/usr/`) to another partition. The 1st 2 are easy to accomplish. The 3rd is an option but should be avoided (the idea is to keep all system related directories on the same boot disk as to not interrupt booting: if the 2nd disk is slow it might not be ready when the system needs them to be ready).